# python production, recommended to create a new user and grant it sudo priviledges to start with?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, sudo, devops, production

Doing a production on EC2, was wondering if it is advisable to start by creating a new user and granting it **sudo privileges**, since not many people do but I have seen it done

Comment: What does this have to do with python?

Comment: What  is your requirement? For example : How create a user with root privileges?

Answer (score 0):

If the alternative would be logging in as root directly, the answer is yes.

It's best to work as a non-root user, with occasional use of sudo.  Doing everyday work as the root user is unsafe.

Comment: when you create a ec2 instance you seem to have some sort of user called ubuntu or amazon or whatever, im unsure if it is actually root itself tbh

Comment: Can you get your work done as this default user?  If so, why would you need to create another user?

Answer (score 0):

Not strictly needed. However, since the username is common and known to everyone, chances are high that someone will be able to access the instance if he comes under the allowed block of IPs and has the pem/ppk file. May be create a password and disable SSH login for ubuntu, or create a new user and setup keybased/password_based login for that user, just to be on the safer side.